# Android Firebase Google Sign In Accounts

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase, google-signin

I'm making an app with Google Firebase for Android. I have implemented Google Sign-In and have a slight problem.

The first time you open the app it works perfectly. A dialog pops up asking which connected google account you want to use with the app. You choose which one and you move on. It is good.

When I sign out of the app I am trying to ask which account the user wants to use like it does on the first opening but it doesn't work. It logs in immediately with your last account.

**How do I get this "choose a google account" dialog to popup every login attempt?**

BTW I am using the default code recommended to sign in with google / firebase.

Thanks!